# How to configure Oracle SQL Developer can store Thai language data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a problem with storing thai language data in Oracle SQL Developer. When I update data with Thai language, the data in table show strange language ¿¿¿¿¿¿ like below :
[image]

Anyone can help me config to store both english and thai language in database? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect SQL Developer is a victim here, while database's character set is a culprit. What does

```
select * from nls_database_parameters;
```

return? Check `NLS_CHARACTERSET` value; should be **AL32UTF8**. If it is not, what is it, then? Note that you might need to *upgrade* the database so that its character set actually *is* AL32UTF8.

Comment: I checked, the LNS_CHARACTERSET value is WE8MSWIN1252. How can I upgraded this value?

Comment: Right; your character set can't display Thai characters. Have a look at **Character set migration**, here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011 (this is 12c database version; if you use some other, search for it).

Comment: If the `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` value in `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS` is AL32UTF8 or AL16UTF16, the OP can probably solve the problem by defining fields like `AGENT_NAME_THAI` as `NVARCHAR2()` instead of `VARCHAR2()`, without going through the headache of upgrading the database characterset across the board.  It depends how prevalent their need for international characters is.